# How to paginate ForeignKey instances in DetailView

Tags: django, pagination

I have written simple blog and my problem is how to use Django pagination to paginate `ForeignKey Comments` In a DetailView of post. I know that Django provides comments framework but for learning purposes my own simple comment system is what i want.
My `models.py`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    comment_author = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text="Enter your nickname.")
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
```

Views.py:

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
```

And template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block title %}
<title>Blog Post</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div>
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
  <em>{{post.post_date}} by {{post.author}}</em> {% if post.author == user %}<a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href="{% url 'edit_post' post.id %}">Edit</a>|<a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href="{% url 'delete_post' post.id %}">Delete</a>{%endif%}
  {%if post.image %}<div class="post-image"><img src="{{post.image.url}}"></div>{%endif%}
  <div class="post-content"><p>{{post.post_text}}</p></div>

  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
      <h4>Comments</h4>
      {%if post.comment %}
      {%for comment in post.comment.all %}
      <hr>
        <em>Posted by {{comment.comment_author}} on {{comment.comment_date}}</em>
        <p>{{comment.comment_text}}</p>

  {%endfor%}
  {%endif%}
  <a href="{%url 'comment_post' post.id%}" class='btn btn-success'>Add a comment</a>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

My pagination is already in `base_generic.html` all I am looking for is how to extend my class based view to paginate comments instances only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn this around a bit. Instead of showing a detail page for Post and then paginating the comments, you could think of this as a list page for comments along with their associated post. ListView already includes pagination functionality; all you therefore need to do is to filter the comments by post and add the post itself to the context. So:

```
class CommentListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Comment

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']  # or whatever your URL is
        return super().get_context_data(post=self.object)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post=self.object)
```

And your template becomes:

```
  ...
  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
      <h4>Comments</h4>
      {%for comment in object_list %}
      <hr>
        <em>Posted by {{comment.comment_author}} on {{comment.comment_date}}</em>
        <p>{{comment.comment_text}}</p>

  {%endfor%}
  ... pagination links here...
```

Comment: Thanks that is solving my question! `def get_context_data(self, pk):
        self.object = Post.objects.get(pk=self.pk) 
        return super().get_context_data(post=self.object)` How would this be different from kwargs ?